# Can't install statsmodels in Enthought Canopy on OSX Mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, enthought, canopy, statsmodels

I'm using the Package manager to try and install statsmodels in Canopy on my MacBook with Mavericks.

I got this error:
**Action: install statsmodels-0.5.0-2.egg
The package manager has encountered error
HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND: https://api.enthought.com/eggs/osx-64/patsy-0.2.0-1.egg**

So I tried installing patsy also via the package manager and got the same message:
**Action: install patsy-0.2.0-1.egg
The package manager has encountered error
HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND: https://api.enthought.com/eggs/osx-64/patsy-0.2.0-1.egg**

Comment: Hi talkterps, we're looking into this. I assume you are using the free version of Canopy, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing patsy and statsmodels using pip.

Comment: Cheers, that worked a treat this time.  I had tried that strategy originally but was getting an error about it being a virtual environment.  Restart must have straightened that out.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see that you solved the problem using `pip`. That's perfectly fine, but it will not allow you to get automatic updates through the command line command `enpkg`, or the Canopy package manager.

The problem was on our side: the packages had been incorrectly labelled as "commercial". It should be fixed now.

Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Thank-you for the update, yes I was trying out the Free version.